# Shutdown Current Vagrant Image inside the box

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I know I can use `vagrant up` and `vagrant destroy`/`vagrant halt` to start and stop the box. However, I have a job running on vagrant that will take a long time. And I want to add some code at the end of my python script to totally blow away the vagrant image it is running on after the job finishes.

I tried adding `sudo shutdown now` command to the end of my code but the box itself is still running as I can see from Virtualbox GUI.

Can anyone point me to the right direction how can I terminate the virtual machine totally within the virtualmachine.

(Worst scenario, I need to write a simple HTTP service on the host machine that, maybe when it finishes, will send terminate myself command to a route and the host machine will kill the virtualbox outiside.)

Here is a [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/627419/vagrant-vm-run-as-a-crontab-job-then-destroy-itself-or-power-off) might gave you more information about what I am trying to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
---
# filename.yml
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: Shutdown localhost
    sudo: yes
    shell: "shutdown now"
```

You can run this file using ansible-playbook filename.yml and it will do the work )))